# Codename One: Implementing a calculation for a fluid tracker

Tags: java, codenameone

I am trying to implement a recurrent addition calculation. This should get the current quantity (from the Quantity textfield) and the saved quantity (total quantity to be saved), outputting the total result below the 'Results' heading. [View of tabbed page for calculation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/082nJ.jpg)

I have tried the following code, but it contains errors and uses a Dialog to output the result (which is not what I want).

```
addItem.addComponent(selectItem);
    TextField quantity = new TextField("", "Quantity (ml or g)", 4, TextArea.NUMERIC);
    addItem.addComponent(quantity);
    Button add = new Button("Add");
    addItem.addComponent(add);       
    TextArea results = new TextArea("Results");
    addItem.addComponent(results);
    //TextArea total = new TextArea("Add Item");
    //addItem.addComponent(total);

//--------------------------------------------------------------
    add.addActionListener((ActionEvent ev) -> {
        Storage s = Storage.getInstance();
Integer addition = 0;
// Read my "Hello World" string back from storage
addition = (Integer)s.readObject("total");
int d = Int.parseInt(quantity.getText());
Integer total = addition + quantity;
// Save the "Hello World" string to storage
s.writeObject("total", total);
Dialog.show("", total, "OK", "Cancel");
    });
//--------------------------------------------------------------

    return addItem;
```

I would therefore appreciate any advice and guidance on how this could be implemented in my code.

Answer (score 0):

To present it in a table , you can use easily GridLayout in this way :

```
Container ctrResultTable = new Container(new GridLayout(1,3)); 
//Define a new container associated to a gridlayout with 1 row and 1 column
ctrResult.addComponent(new Label(d.toString()));
ctrResult.addComponent(new Label(total.toString()));
ctrResult.addComponent(new Label((total/target*100).toString()));
//Because you use a value inside a function, addItem should be initialized as final
addItem.addComponent(ctrResult);
```

But i can't do nothing for your code error because i can't see the full code here